# How can we hide play,timeline control from Video tag

Tags: html, css

I want to hide all the media control which appear in Video tag.
Below mentioned CSS is working fine in Chrome but not in IE

```
video::-webkit-media-controls {
display: none;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show video controls:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
```

To hide video controls:

```
<video width="320" height="240">
```

[Supported from IE 9 and up.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_video_controls.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Just not setting it in HTML should do:

```
<video width="400" height="200" autoplay="autoplay">
<source src="video/somevid.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Or via CSS try with `!important`:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls {
  display:none !important;
}
```